# Returning a mock object from a mock object

Tags: design, programming-practices, unit-testing, tdd, mocking

I'm trying to return an object when mocking a parser class. This is the test code using PHPUnit 3.7

```
    //set up the result object that I want to be returned from the call to parse method
    $parserResult= new ParserResult();
    $parserResult->setSegment('some string');        

    //set up the stub Parser object
    $stubParser=$this->getMock('Parser');
    $stubParser->expects($this->any())
               ->method('parse')
               ->will($this->returnValue($parserResult));

    //injecting the stub to my client class
    $fileWriter= new FileWriter($stubParser);
    $output=$fileWriter->writeStringToFile();
```

Inside my `writeStringToFile()` method I'm using `$parserResult` like this:

```
writeStringToFile(){
   //Some code...
    $parserResult=$parser->parse();
    $segment=$parserResult->getSegment();//that's why I set the segment in the test.
}
```

Should I mock `ParserResult` in the first place, so that the mock returns a mock?
Is it good design for mocks to return mocks?

Is there a better approach to do this all?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general having a chain of mocks returning other mocks is considered a code smell in tests.

That being said, the answer of whether this is good idea is of course "it depends".

About your ParserResult object - if it is a small value object then constructing it and passing it in is probably a good idea.

If it is a large object with dependancies of its own, then mocking it would be a better option. Not mocking it would increase the coupling in your tests.

Another question to ask about the design is what is the result of ParserResult.getSegment used for? Perhaps a Tell Don't Ask style might be better, can you tell ParserResult or Parser to do something with the segment information instead of extracting it and then operating on it?

Comment: well the thing is my `FileWriter` class which I inject the parser into will probably have about 4 other injected parsers into it. Each one of them will return a `ParserResult` object. Then `$output` will be constructed from the 5 `ParserResult` objects.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a collection of Parsers which will give you a collection of ParserResults. Perhaps also another object which does the formatting of the output of those results which then your FileWriter would write to the file. If you go down that route then you'd only be mocking this ParserCollection object. But I feel I am speculating too much; my advice is to go the direction you are going in and pay attention to the pain points and code smells as you add more Parsers to the mix.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a good idea to mock the smallest and closest possible set of dependencies to the class you are testing.
The idea is to reduce the test into the simplest possible scenario so it's easy to ensure the test is correct and that only tests one thing.

If you return a mock you are testing two separate things, the function that consumes the mock and the class that now creates and returns  the mock.

So test the consumer and the producer of the ParserResult separately.